# Faster way of getting number of key frames than "show_frames" in ffprobe?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm making a little in-house utility using `ffmpg` and `ffprobe`. Works fine and does what is needed: give a count of the number of key frames in a video file plus some other details.

Alas, with the large video files this will be used on it can take many seconds for `show_frames` to return – and I then have to parse the JSON dump of frame data and keep a running count of the total key frames.

Is there a faster way? Perhaps it is listed in the "stream" or "format" data dumps and I am not recognizing what it is being called? I've been through the `ffmpg` and `ffprobe` docs and didn't find anything else.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem ? Am also facing the same issue of parsing mp4 stss atom from http stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MP4 and MOV files, you can get this info by reading the contents of the [STSS](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=QuickTime_container#stss) box

You can use a tool like [MP4parser](https://sites.google.com/site/james2013notes/home/mp4-file-format), which will generate a log file with an entry like this:

```
/moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stss                              @ 0x1d7218e
  Box size: 0x74    version: 0x0    flags: 0x0
  entry_count:              0x19
    sample_number:
    0x1    0x86    0x180    0x27a    ....
```

That entry count (in Hex) is the number you want.

Alternatively, [atomicparsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) will also tell you of the location of the STSS within the file and you can then read it directly.